# Comparing Two Hashmaps in Java

Tags: java

What's the recommended approach for comparing hashmaps in Java for equality so that I can determine if they have identical keys and values?

```
Map<String,List<String>> data1 = new HashMap<>();
data1.put("file1", Arrays.asList("one","two","three"));

Map<String,List<String>> data2 = new HashMap<>();
data2.put("file1", Arrays.asList("one","two","three"));
```

Comment: [`Map.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Simply `data1.equals(data2)`

Comment: The question may have some other considerations, like: what is more efficient (faster)? If the keys are identical, does it mean the values are implied? more docs: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/hashmap/compare-two-hashmaps/

Answer (score 0):

By default, `HashMap.equals()` method compares two hashmaps by key-value pairs. It means both hashmap instances must have exactly same key-value pairs and both must be of same size.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `equals` method.

```
boolean equals = data1.equals(data2);
```